# Vim EasyMotion for VS Code not activating

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

Does anyone use Vim with VSCode?
For some reason, my `<leader>` key (space), does not activate the easy-motion plugin (I made sure it is enabled in the settings), but just moves the cursor to the right once.
I am new to VS Code, am I missing something? I still haven't figured out how `.vimrc` works with VS Code.

TIA!

Comment: Looks like your `.vimrc` file is conflicting with the vim plugin, first disable use of `vimrc` and then try to use easymotion.

Comment: @isAif tried this, thank you. I believe VS Code does not emulate vim properly, so I might as well fully switch back to the regular terminal vim. Thank you tho! 
I will still appreciate any useful advice :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not nessesary to use .vimrc file for vscode unless you want some customized behaviors.

- Make sure you've enbaled the easymotion in vsvim settings:

  `"vim.easymotion": true`

  (in your settings.json file)
- When it comes to VSCode, easymotion will be triggered by **double press** <leader> key. 
  Different from Terminal Vim, for example: (in your case <leader> is set to <kbd>space</kbd>)

  <kbd>space</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>

  after you press the above keys, your status bar should look like
  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mphjN.png).

Hope it would help you get into Visual Studio Code quickly.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the double press on leader.  I was confused as to why EasyMotion wasn't working when leader works fine in consoles.  VS Code quirks!  \o/

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know, vim mode in VS code isn't configured by .vimrc file, instead, it's configured by `setting.json`. You can find how to configure them in this [README.md](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/master/README.md).

Check that:

- `"vim.leader"`is set to `<Space>`
- go to `preference -> Keyboard shortcut` in VS code. Make sure that you did not customize any command to any shortcut starting with `<space>`.  (I made this mistake before)
- the timeout length of the leader key is pretty short, make sure you press, let's say, `'w'` key right after `<leader><leader>`

I hope this would help

Comment: Another thing I needed to do was disable "Add period with double-space" on OSX so that the `<leader><leader>` combo registered smoothly.

Comment: @tiki: tysm for it as i was confused why easymotion was not being triggered smoothly

Comment: Same here, I was searching endlessly for why there was a bizarre delay when using <space> as my leader key!

Answer (score 2):

This has been bugging me forever. I just realized that my mac keyboard settings have a “Add period with double-space” configuration.

Disabling this fixed the issue for me.

'System Preferences' -> 'keyboard' -> 'input sources' -> toggle off 'Add period with double-space'

MacOs 13.x